# Как указать имя отправителя письма?

Tags: python, django

Я использую батарейку *django-registration* для регистрации, поэтому, думаю, код скидывать не имеет смысла.

Как при отправке письма для подтверждения регистрации указать имя отправителя (например, «Сайт learning log»), чтобы у получателя отображалось именно это имя вместо email-адреса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать свой шаблон письма - файл с именем activation_email.txt, который должен лежать в папке templates/registration. См. [документацию](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/quickstart.html#required-templates)